# nested list hacker rank test case python

Tags: python, list, solution

the following is my code for hackerrank nested list problem to print the name of second last score of student. I am beginning my journey in python exploration. this code fails in two test cases listed below...can anybody help me with that.

1. 4
   Sona
   -25.001
   Mona
   -25.0001
   Mini
   -25.000
   Rita
   -25.0

2.4
Shadab
8
Varun
8.9
Sarvesh
9.5
Harsh
10

---

```
n=int(input())
l=[]
for i in range(n*2) :
    ele=input()
    l.append(ele) 
l2=[]

for i in range(1,n*2,2) :
    l2.append(l[i])

l2.sort()
a=min(l2)

for i in range(n) :
    for i in l2 :
        if i == a :
            l2.remove(i)


b=min(l2)
l3=[]
for i in range(n*2) :
    if l[i] == b :
        l3.append((l[i-1]))

l3.sort()
for i in range(len(l3)) :
    print(l3[i])
```

---

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "second last score of student"? And provide expected output for your example input?

Comment: It would be good to provide a link to the question. It is probably this question: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem
It would also be helpful if you showed how you tried to test these cases and what you got as a response (and what you were expecting asa response).

Comment: @atru it refers to the student with the second least score in the provided list.   in the test case provided -- for 1. the output should be mona and for 2 it should be varun

Comment: @SinanKurmus yeah thats the question...the expexted outputs are : for 1 is mona but im getting mini...and also for 2 its varum , my output is shadab.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me. you can assign inf instead of 1000 if you want .

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    d_list=[]
    low=[1000,1000]
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        val = float(input())
        if val < low[0]:
            low[1]=low[0]
            low[0]=val
        elif val < low[1] and val >low[0]:
            low[1]=val
        if val<=low[1]:
            d_list.append([name,val])
    for student in sorted(d_list):
        if student[1]==low[1]:
            print(student[0])
```

Comment: okay this works thank you. Could u help me to correct my code ?

Comment: hi, after taking input in through ele=input() , you are not converting the score values  to float from the string. input() always provide string . and when you are selecting min(l2), it is doing string comparison. print a(i.e. first minimum), you will see the wrong output.  bcz 10>8 but '10'<'8' and same for others. change the score to float, it will work i blv

Comment: before first for loop use a temp_var and in input line use below 
Temp=True
for i in range(n*2) :
    ele=input() if True else float(input())
    Temp=~Temp

Comment: @sumantrai if this answered your question, consider giving credits as in [What should I do when someone answers my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
no_of_students = int(input())

records = []

for i in range(no_of_students):

    name = input()

    score = float(input())

    records.append([name, score])

records = dict(records)

scores = sorted(set(records.values()))

second_lowest_score = scores[1]

second_lowest_students = [name for name,score in records if 
score==second_lowest_score]

second_lowest_students.sort()

for name in second_lowest_students:
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = int(input())
name = []
marks = []
for i in range(t):
    n = input()
    m = input()
    name.append(n)
    marks.append(float(m))
d_marks = []
for i in range(t):
    if(marks[i] not in d_marks):
        d_marks.append(marks[i])
d_marks.sort()
s_min = float(d_marks[1])
l = []
for i in range(t):
    if(float(marks[i]) == s_min):
        l.append(name[i])
l.sort()

for i in range(len(l)):
    print(l[i])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).